# Running ansible-playbook with cron

Tags: cron, ansible

I want to schedule following playbook:

---

```
    - hosts: win_hv_hosts
      tasks:
      - name: Return list of found updates and log to C:\ans_found_updates.txt
        win_updates:
                category_names: SecurityUpdates
                state: searched
                log_path: C:/ans_found_updates.txt
```

My win_hv_hosts:

```
[win_hv_hosts]
192.168.1.36
192.168.1.37
[win_hv_hosts:vars]
ansible_user = user@DOMAIN.COM
ansible_password = Password
ansible_connection = winrm
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
ansible_port = 5985
```

When running manually

```
sudo ansible-playbook win_check_updates.yml -f 10
```

everything is OK. I want to schedule it to run with cron:

```
0 * * * * /usr/bin/ansible-playbook /etc/ansible/win_check_updates.yml -f 10 > /home/user/crontab.log
```

I am getting errors:

```
fatal: [192.168.1.36]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "plaintext: the specified credentials were rejected by the server", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [192.168.1.37]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "plaintext: the specified credentials were rejected by the server", "unreachable": true}
PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
192.168.1.36               : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
192.168.1.37               : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

What I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
ansible_winrm_transport=ntlm
```

solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Then credentials error is because you have specified the password in plain text. Encrypt the password using encrypt or use ansible vault.

In terms of normal execution i.e without from you have provided password in plain text, right ?

If this is working then some issues with the ansible invocation

Also why you have used sudo to execute playbook ?

Comment: I encrypted playbook file and my cron task is looks like this:     0 * * * * /usr/bin/ansible-playbook /etc/ansible/win_check_updates.yml  --vault-id /etc/ansible/sec-pass. Unfortunately still getting same error.

Comment: @ArkadyKarasin can you re run with debug logs i.e run ansible with -vvvv

Comment: 2019-04-11 17:30:02,379 p=3889 u=root |  ansible-playbook 2.7.9
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.15+ (default, Oct  2 2018, 22:12:08) [GCC 8.2.0]

Comment: 2019-04-11 17:30:02,379 p=3889 u=root |  Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
2019-04-11 17:30:02,392 p=3889 u=root |  /etc/ansible/hosts did not meet host_list requirements, check plugin documentation if this is unexpected
2019-04-11 17:30:02,403 p=3889 u=root |  Parsed /etc/ansible/hosts inventory source with ini plugin
2019-04-11 17:30:02,758 p=3889 u=root |  PLAYBOOK: win_check_updates.yml ************************************************

Comment: 2019-04-11 17:30:02,758 p=3889 u=root |  1 plays in /etc/ansible/win_check_updates.yml
2019-04-11 17:30:02,776 p=3889 u=root |  PLAY [win_hv_hosts] ************************************************************
2019-04-11 17:30:02,787 p=3889 u=root |  TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
2019-04-11 17:30:02,788 p=3889 u=root |  task path: /etc/ansible/win_check_updates.yml:2
2019-04-11 17:30:03,391 p=3889 u=root |  Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/windows/setup.ps1

Comment: 2019-04-11 17:30:03,403 urllib3.connectionpool Starting new HTTP connection (1): 192.168.1.36:5985
2019-04-11 17:30:03,408 urllib3.connectionpool http://192.168.1.36:5985 "POST /wsman HTTP/1.1" 401 0
2019-04-11 17:30:03,414 p=3889 u=root |  fatal: [192.168.1.36]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "plaintext: the specified credentials were rejected by the server", 
    "unreachable": true
}

Comment: @ArkadyKarasin since you have encrypted the password. the issue seems to not with encryption but with password. https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/16478 please check this.

Comment: I guess I got the issue the username that is getting passed is root it should not be root. It should be the windows domain user.

Comment: Event logged on my desktop:        Account For Which Logon Failed:
     Security ID:  NULL SID
     Account Name:  user@DOMAIN.COM
    Account Domain:  myDesktopName  So, I think ansible not specified domain name when tried to login

Comment: seems to me related to the username and authentication with windows only

Comment: Thank you @error404!    Finaly I found solution: **ansible_winrm_transport=ntlm** .    I can't believe... I spent few days to find this magic formula!!!